# How to do a Spring Unit Test of a Service layer that use Repository?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I'm developing a Spring REST application, and have a **Service** that access the database (using a **Repository**) and recover N last documents (I'm using MongoDB).

So, my **Service** has this function:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<MessageLogViewDto>> listLogs(int total) {
  // Request the entities using PageRequest to list only last N registers ordered by DATE (DESC). I don't known a better way to do this!
  PageRequest page = new PageRequest(0, total, Sort.Direction.DESC, "Date");
  Page<MessageLog> messages = logRepo.findAll(page);

  // Convert the Entity to DTO
  List<MessageLogViewDto> messageList = messages.getContent().stream().map(
    message -> convertDto.toMessageLogView(message)).collect(Collectors.toList());

  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(messageList);
}
```

(convertDto is a class to convert entity to Dto).

Ok, how to do a unit test of this?
I read on several blogs that a Unit Test should not connect to a database.
This unit test can be made very simple if I use a real test database, but I like to known what's the better way to do this test without a database (if possible).

I can mock the repository and the function `findAll`, but if I mock findAll method, I must mock the return value too. I don't know how to mock a `Page<Object>` response, because `Page` is a interface, and I will have to implement all the methods in the mock.

For my test, I was thinking in create 3 random `message` entity, with different dates, and check if only the last message was returned.

something like this:

```
@Test
  public void shouldReturnLastMessage() {
    int total = 1;

    // mock findAll
    // mock first entity 
    // mock a second entity
    // mock a third entity
    // ??? = must return a Page<MessageLog> with 3 entitys, how?
    when(dbLogRepoMock.findAll(any(PageRequest.class))).thenReturn(???);

    // call the service
    List<MessageLogViewDto> result = logService.listLogs(total).join();

    // check returned value
    assertThat(result.size()).isEqualTo(total);
    assertThat(result.get(0).getMensagem()).isEqualTo("third message"); // last message

    // check if repository was called
    verify(dbLogRepoMock).findAll(any(PageRequest.class));
}
```

Any help?

Comment: `.thenReturn(new PageImpl<>(someListOfTestData))` or `thenAnswer` with some answer testing the args.

Comment: tks @RC. Trying right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a mildly controversial opinion, but I would focus on unit testing *only* your converter as there is no other meaningful custom logic in this method.

Looking at the method it does:

```
// 1 - Create an instance of a Spring class
PageRequest page = new PageRequest(0, total, Sort.Direction.DESC, "Date");
// 2 - Query a Spring Repository with the Spring Class
Page<MessageLog> messages = logRepo.findAll(page);

// 3 - CUSTOM LOGIC to convert result to custom DTO class
List<MessageLogViewDto> messageList = messages.getContent().stream().map(
        message -> convertDto.toMessageLogView(message)).collect(Collectors.toList());

// 4 - Return a Java standard CompleteableFuture 
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(messageList);
```

Even if you were to write a unit test for this method,

1 is trivial class instantiation
2 uses result of 1 -  but you'd be creating a mock response anyway so it wouldn't be meaningfully exercising 1. 
3 is your converter logic, which you could write a standalone test for directly
4 is leveraging a core java feature that you are very very unlikely to find a bug with

Additionally, look at the signature of the method:

`public CompletableFuture<List<MessageLogViewDto>> listLogs(int total) {`

It accepts an integer `total` and returns a `CompleteableFuture` (the implementation of which we don't care to test as it's not the core feature of this method / is a built-in) containing a List of elements.  Assumedly a list of size `total`.

Without actually accessing the database, you would have to mock the data returned to be the expected size. The actual logic of determining the size of the result is part of the data access framework, so you wouldn't even be able to validate that the output data size actually matches the input parameter of your method. Not much value there in my estimation.

I generally do not focus on unit-testing data-access methods that are just accessing and returning data without any meaningful logic. In this case the ONLY meaningful logic occurs in your converter, so I would focus on testing that.

you could possibly extract a method like:

```
List<MessageLogViewDTO> convertMessageLogsToMessageLogViewDTO(List<MessageLog> messages) {
  return messages.getContent().stream().map(
    message -> convertDto.toMessageLogView(message)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

and then you can simply test that method with various cases (valid data, empty / null lists, etc.

Comment: tks @Ben. I realized that the mock of returned value must be the expected size. So, my mock just returned a null value, and then check if the repository was called with correct parameters (page size, order by, etc). Then, made another test just for converter.